# Error when trying to upgrade angular 8 to 10

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to upgrade angular 8 application to angular 10 updated all the required dependencies and when I try to run the application I get the following errors. I couldn't find any solution online, anyone know how to fix these errors? Thanks. [Error on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW2Ud.png) [Error displayed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVyYv.png).

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
"@angular/forms": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/router": "^10.2.5",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.2",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
"acorn": "^6.2.0",
"angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
"bootstrap": "4.1.1",
"core-js": "^3.1.4",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"moment": "^2.28.0",
"msal": "^1.4.4",
"ng6-breadcrumbs": "^1.0.7",
"ng7-bootstrap-breadcrumb": "^2.0.0",
"ng7-dynamic-breadcrumb": "^2.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
"ngx-markdown": "^7.1.5",
"ngx-mask": "^2.9.6",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
"upath": "^1.1.2",
"zone.js": "^0.10.3" },

 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.3",
"@angular/cli": "^10.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/language-service": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.15",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.5",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.138",
"@types/node": "^12.6.8",
"angular-ide": "^0.9.70",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
"bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"maven-deploy": "^1.5.0",
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"npm": "^6.12.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
"sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "^5.18.0",
"typescript": "4.0.8",
"webpack": "^4.37.0",
"yarn": "^1.5.1"  }
```

Comment: Itd be great if you could copy and paste the errors you're getting into your question rather than using a link to an image 

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the angular update guide? https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Yeah I followed the exact steps provided on update.angular.io.

Comment: why did you kept the "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1", this need to be updated too